# Nginx Validation failed due to conflict server name

Tags: nginx

we are configuring customized the nginx, while validating the nginx i'm getting below error

```
nginx -t
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "gmottqa.test.att.com" on 0.0.0.0:8080, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "gmottqa.test.att.com" on 0.0.0.0:8443, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Adding nginx config file for troubleshooting the issue, please let me know if anything requried

```
cat nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /opt/app/nginx/logs/error.log error;
pid        /opt/app/nginx/run/nginx.pid;


events {
        worker_connections  4096;
        multi_accept        on;
        use                 epoll;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 400000;

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_tokens off;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /opt/app/nginx/logs/access.log  main;
    keepalive_timeout                   15;
    keepalive_requests                  1024;
    client_header_timeout                       15;
    client_body_timeout                 15;
    send_timeout                                15;
    sendfile                            on;
    tcp_nopush                          on;
    tcp_nodelay                         on;

    # enable gzip compression
        gzip off;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_static on;
    # end gzip configuration

    include /opt/app/nginx/conf/conf.d/*.conf;
```

can you please some where i have check this issue

Comment: can you share content of nginx.conf file ?

Comment: sure, i'm updating file

Comment: Hi Van, can you please help me on this

Comment: are you using linux?

Comment: Can you share files in include /opt/app/nginx/conf/conf.d/*.conf

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you're using Linux.

In the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, depending on your editor it may have left a `temp` file e.g. `default~` or the file could be named `.save` or something like this.

Just run `$ ls -lah` to see which files are unintended to be there.

Delete this file, it should solve your problem.

Comment: i'm not having the file name called cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Comment: add your server blocks in the post please. and these are just warning have you checked whether `nginx` is running or not?